# How can a node X without right child have a successor?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a trouble understanding what's a successor of a node `X` whenever it doesn't have a right child.

From what I had understood, if a node `X` had no right child, then it would not have a successor.

But my textbook says the following:

> If the right sub-tree of node `X` is empty and `X` has a successor `Y`...

How can `X` have a successor when it has not right child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The successor is simply the next element in the ordered sequence; it doesn't necessarily have to be a child element.

For example, the successor of `5` below is `7`:

```
  7
 / \
5   8
```

Comment: But there is various types of successor?

Answer (score 1):

The successor of a node `X` is the *smallest greater* element `S` in the tree with respect to `X`. That is, for all nodes in the set `G = { Si | Si > X }`, then `S` is an element of `G` and `S <= Si`, for `i=1..n`.

In a BST, for any node `X`, all elements in left subtree of `X` are smaller than `X`, while all elements in its right subtree are greater than it.

### Scenarios

Now consider `X` as an arbitrary node in your tree, and let `P` be its parent node. In both of the following cases it does **not** matter if `X` has or not a left subtree, which contains elements that are smaller than `X`.

1. **`X` has a right subtree**

   The successor of `X` *by definition* lies in right subtree. The smallest element of the right subtree is the leftmost element, which is the successor of `X`. If the right subtree contains only one node then that is the successor of `X`.
2. **`X` has no right subtree**

   1. **`X` is the *left child* of its parent `P`**

      Then parent `P` is the successor.
   2. **`X` is a right child of its parent `P`**

      Then the **first** ancestor of `X`, lets call it `A`, such that `X` falls in the left subtree of `A` is the successor of `X`.

### Example

```
        10
       /  \
      5    14
     / \   /  \
    3   7  11  15
   / \  /
   1 4  6
```

---

1. Examples for case 1

   - Successor of 3 is 4  (or, similarly, the successor of 14 is 15)
   - Successor of 10 is 11 (or, similarly, the successor of 5 is 6)
2. Examples for case 2

   - Successor of 7 is 10 (or, similarly, the successor of 4 is 5)
   - Successor of 11 is 14 (or, similarly, the successor of 6 is 7)

Comment: I did a great improvement to this answer, and I believe now the explanation should be very clear.